# Using addjoin in Hibernate throws class cast exception

Tags: hibernate, hibernateexception

**Query**

```
    List <t1> t1List  = hibernateSession.createSqlQuery
("select * from t1 join t2 on t1.id = t2.id")  
.addEntity("t1Alias",t1.class)
.addJoin("j1","t1Alias.id").list();


        for(t1 object : t1List  ){
        log.debug(t1.id);     //throws class cast exception 
                              //Cannot convert object to class t1
        }
```

but the same code executes if i remove the addJoin (t1Alias.id)

Can some explain why ?

---

Edit 1:

t1 :t2
N:1

Comment: post the mapping please.

Answer (score 0):

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html

The `<t1>` type parameter isn't necessary when calling `hibernateSession.createSqlQuery` (it returns a `List` of `Object` arrays).Removing it should solve your problems.

Comment: i tried that too, same error.If you see in my post too the issue is not at place where the list is assigned , but when the list is iterated